# How to split text into lines based on the number of words?

Tags: php, string

```
<body>
<?php
    $text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
    $newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");
    echo $newtext;
?>
</body>
```

In the above code, a newline is displayed after every 20 **characters**.

It outputs:

```
The quick brown fox
jumped over the lazy
dog.
```

Instead of characters, I want to be able to split based on the number of words. For example, if I set the words per line as 4, it should output:

```
The quick brown fox
jumped over the lazy
dog.
```

How can I achieve this using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) to split the sentence into an array of words and use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk) to split that array into multiple chunks of desired length:

```
$wordsPerLine = 4;
$words = preg_split('/(?<=\w)\b\s*/', $text);  
$chunks = array_chunk($words, $wordsPerLine);

foreach ($chunks as $arr) {
    echo implode(' ', $arr), '<br />';
}
```

Output:

```
The quick brown fox
jumped over the lazy
dog.
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/101904)

Comment: <?php
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$wordsPerLine = 4;
$words = preg_split('/(?<=\w)\b\s*/', $text);  
$chunks = array_chunk($words, $wordsPerLine);

foreach ($chunks as $arr) {
    echo implode(' ', $arr), PHP_EOL;
}
?> this code is showing the whole string in single line....please help

Comment: @user3138522: Change `PHP_EOL` to `<br/>`, then.

Answer (score 1):

Change the $numOfWords as needed

```
<?php
     $text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
     $newtext = explode(" ", $text);

     $numOfWords = 3;

     for($i=0;$i<sizeof($newtext);$i++){
        echo $newtext[$i]." ";
        if(((($i+1) % $numOfWords) == 0) && $i!=0){
            echo '<br />';
        }
     }


 ?>
```

Comment: There was a little bug, and now it is fixed.